# MySql PDO access denied when passing pdo object to another class

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, pdo

I have 2 linux VMs with below configuration:

**VM 1:**
`OS: Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.4`
`Apache: 2.2.23`
`PHP: 5.5.3`
`MySQL: 5.5.28`
`PHP config: './configure'  '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--prefix=/usr/local/apache2/php' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache2/php' '--disable-cgi' '--with-zlib' '--with-gettext' '--with-gdbm' '--with-sqlite3' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl=/usr/lib' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/libjpeg.so' '--with-png-dir=/usr/lib/libpng.so' '--enable-soap' '--enable-bcmath'`

**VM 2:**
`OS: Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.4`
`Apache: 2.4.6`
`PHP: 5.3.27`
`MySQL: 5.6.13`
`PHP config: './configure'  '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--prefix=/usr/local/apache2/php' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache2/php' '--disable-cgi' '--with-zlib' '--with-gettext' '--with-gdbm' '--with-sqlite3' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl=/usr/lib' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/libjpeg.so' '--with-png-dir=/usr/lib/libpng.so' '--enable-soap' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-pear' '--enable-ftp' '--with-openssl'`

I have a php class which connects to a MySQL database using PDO using the following code:

```
    try {            
        $this->maindb = new PDO(PDO_MYSQL_HOST_DBNAME, PDO_MYSQL_USER, PDO_MYSQL_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $this->maindb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);            
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Error connecting database: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

This part works fine, and data gets inserted to the database as expected.

Strangely towards the end of the class, when I create an object of another class and pass `$this->maindb` object to one of its methods to write some more data, It fails with `'SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 'team'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'` error.

My problem is, the same code works fine on VM1, and fails on VM2 as described. I have tried these options:

- With both persistent and non-persistent connections.
- Used MySql `root` user privileges.

I have no idea what might be causing this problem. Please help me sort this out.

**NOTE**: I prefer any solution which doesn't involve downgrading packages.

Comment: Remember that MySQL allows to set permissions at database, table and even column level.

Comment: Question #1: Why do you create another connection in the same class instead of using one opened previously? Question #2: what's unclear with error message? It has nothing to do with packages but with db credentials only

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - I have granted all privileges to the particular user on that database. I mentioned that I tried root user also.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Answer #1: I only created some other object, and passed the same connection to that object. I didn't try to create another connection. Answer #2: You're right. But, I had to consider that since It failed for MySql `root` user.

Comment: Having a user called `root` does not automatically grant him all the available permissions. You still need to find out what query runs when it fails and double-check all permissions.

Comment: It seems you are - the error message belongs to connection code. Nevertheless, you still need to find out **what query runs when it fails**. Most likely your usually wrong way of using \try catch makes you unable to track down the erroneous spot

Comment: Also, your comment contradicts with question title: "login fails for second connection". So, is it "the same" or "second" connection?

Comment: It fails when this query runs `LOAD DATA INFILE '/opt/web/htdocs/../billanalyzer_data/bills/data/S0011582768/tbl_anal_results.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_anal_results FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`.  Could this be a permission issue?

Comment: I have changed the title.

Comment: What about googleing for the error message?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I gave `FILE` permission to the user, and it is working now.